# Recuperar datos de una tabla de una Base de Datos con condiciones incompletas

Tags: mysql

En una tabla de una Base de Datos tengo lo siguiente:

```
id_video | nom_video 
---------+-----------------
1        | Base de datos 
2        | Programación
```

Con la siguiente instrucción recupero lo que es igual a "Base de datos", pero como recupero lo que contenga parte del nombre por ejemplo si pongo solo "base" o "datos".

```
select * 
  from unidadAprendizaje 
  where nom_video="Base de datos";
```

Answer (score 1):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Para hacer lo que quieres existe el operador **`LIKE`**, el cual se usa comúnmente para seleccionar columnas con patrones específicos. Usar el operador `LIKE` de la manera correcta es esencial para aumentar el rendimiento de la consulta. Se usa a menudo en la cláusula `WHERE` de la instrucción `SELECT`.

MySQL proporciona dos caracteres comodín para usar con el operador `LIKE`, el porcentaje (`%`) y el subrayado (`_`).

- El comodín porcentaje (`%`) permite hacer coincidir cualquier cadena de cero o más caracteres.
- El comodín de subrayado (`_`) permite hacer coincidir cualquier carácter individual.

Veamos algunos ejemplos:

Supongamos que deseas buscar un `nom_video` que contenga la palabra *base*  **solamente**, puedes usar el comodín `%` de este modo:

```
SELECT * 
FROM unidadAprendizaje 
WHERE nom_video LIKE '%base%';
```

O quieres encontrar las palabras *base* O *datos*:

```
SELECT * 
FROM unidadAprendizaje 
WHERE nom_video LIKE '%base%' OR nom_video LIKE '%datos%';
```

O quieres encontrar las palabras *base* Y *datos*:

```
SELECT * 
FROM unidadAprendizaje 
WHERE nom_video LIKE '%base%' AND nom_video LIKE '%datos%';
```

En estos casos de usa la notación `%patron%`, o sea, el patrón encerrado entre el comodín `%`, esto se puede entender como *contiene [patron]*.

---

`LIKE` tienes más usos, según la posición del comodín, en los ejemplos anteriores vimos su uso, rodeando la palabra por el comodín `%`.

Pero si usamos esta notación: `patron%`, estaríamos buscando valores *que **empiecen** por [patron]*:

```
SELECT * 
FROM unidadAprendizaje 
WHERE nom_video LIKE 'base%';
```

Y si usamos esta notación: `%patron`, estaríamos buscando valores *que **terminen** por [patron]*:

```
SELECT * 
FROM unidadAprendizaje 
WHERE nom_video LIKE '%base';
```

---

Y ya finalmente, sólo para mostrar cómo funciona el otro comodín. Si quieres encontrar los valores que empiecen por `b`, tengan cualquier caracter y luego siga una `s`, usas el comodín: `_`

```
SELECT * 
FROM unidadAprendizaje 
WHERE nom_video LIKE 'b_s';
```

En el caso de este comodín, cada `_` representa un caracter, puedes escribir consultas así por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * 
FROM unidadAprendizaje 
WHERE nom_video LIKE 'b__e';
```

Ahí encontraría valores como: `base`, `bate`, `bote` ...

Hay muchos más usos y combinaciones de `LIKE`, los puedes ver en la documentación.

---

#### Enlaces

- [`LIKE` en el Manual de Referencia de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)
- [MySQL LIKE en `mysqltutorial.org`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like/)